# Error: failed to push some refs to ssh without username

Tags: jenkins, ssh, gerrit

I am having problems pushing my changes from Jenkins server to Gerrit server because of this error:

```
+ git checkout origin/release_6.3.0
Previous HEAD position was 6c1313da... Fixes getting secret posts when searching posts by market.
HEAD is now at a9490de6... Fixes channels routes.
+ git rev-parse Deploy_Stage_6.3.0_RC210_Her
+ git tag Deploy_Stage_6.3.0_RC210_Her
+ git push origin Deploy_Stage_6.3.0_RC210_Her
debug1: Connecting to gerrit [XX.XX.XX.X] port 29418.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/mikz/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/mikz/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/mikz/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/mikz/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/mikz/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/mikz/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/mikz/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/mikz/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version GerritCodeReview_2.12 (SSHD-CORE-0.14.0)
debug1: no match: GerritCodeReview_2.12 (SSHD-CORE-0.14.0)
debug1: Authenticating to gerrit:29418 as 'gerrit'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:lZ41xRL6gg58lbJKSIcYDlo54lUVj6lUFOCsj1zfKns
debug1: Host '[gerrit]:29418' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/mikz/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/USER_NAME/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to gerrit ([XX.XX.XX.X]:29418).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending command: git-receive-pack 'PATH'
remote: 
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done            
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2904, received 252760 bytes, in 0.9 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 3225.7, received 280757.7
debug1: Exit status 0
To ssh://gerrit:29418/PATH
 ! [remote rejected]   Deploy_Stage_6.3.0_RC210_Her -> Deploy_Stage_6.3.0_RC210_Her (prohibited by Gerrit)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://gerrit@gerrit:29418/PATH'
Build step 'Conditional step (single)' marked build as failure
Description set: 
Finished: FAILURE
```

Probably  this is because at this line:
To ssh://gerrit:29418/PATH
I don't have the user name, but I don't know how to fix it 

I added the following line in .gitconfig but it doesn't work: 
[url "ssh://gerrit@gerrit:29418/"] 
    insteadOf = ssh://gerrit:29418/

any idea how i can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you execute "git push origin BRANCH" you're pushing straight to the branch bypassing Gerrit. This error (prohibited by Gerrit) means the "gerrit" user doesn't have permission to do that. You need to grant to the user permission to bypass code review or use "refs/for/BRANCH" in your push command.

See more details about this error in Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/error-prohibited-by-gerrit.html).

Comment: user "gerrit" has admin permissions in gerrit

Comment: It isn't enough to be a Gerrit administrator. Administrators have the "Administrate Server" capability assigned but they don't have, by default, all push/create permissions. You need to be sure that "gerrit" user has "Push" access rights on "refs/heads/*". Check also all others permissions listed in the link I've posted.

Comment: here is screenshot of my gerrit settings for "refs/heads/*"
http://prntscr.com/efke62

user gerrit is on Administrators group

Comment: >>>>See more details about this error in Gerrit documentation here.
https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/error-prohibited-by-gerrit.html

That is correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Wrong permission in Gerrit.
All permission should be set according to 
https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/error-prohibited-by-gerrit.html

Comment: Why did you repeat the same answer I've already posted instead of accept my answer?